# Null pointer crash on getActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities()

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, package

I have an app that points to another app in the play store. It is working fine in test and with a lot of subscribers. But for 2 guys I have a null pointer crash on the line: `if (getActivity().getPackageManager()...`

I am in a fragment so I doubt that it's a context issue.
What could be the reason? A permission issue? What test should I add to check for null pointer?

```
private void getApp(){

    final Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + "test");
    final Intent rateAppIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

    if (getActivity().getPackageManager()
       .queryIntentActivities(rateAppIntent, 0).size() > 0)
    {
      startActivity(rateAppIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: just do it `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + "test"));
startActivity(intent);`

Comment: You are trying to check is that app install in the device or not, right? If not then install that app. am I right?

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya: works well. Thanks :)

Comment: @Enamul Haque:I'm simply proposing a user to install the app.

Comment: Yah... I got  it. do solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

> if
>   (getActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(rateAppIntent,
>   0).size() > 0)

For your Requirement using **`getActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities`** totally unnecessary .

Simple Way

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + "test"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: That means you are going to open play store every time? No checking! Cutting head to remove headache!!!

Comment: @EnamulHaque Good idea !

Comment: hmmm... I think finally I may take the approach if(getactivity() == null)... ;o)

Comment: @narb no problem!

Comment: good debate though. and good remarks from Yashar. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1):

`getActivity()` could return `null` if your fragment is not attached to activity. You can check it with `isAdded()` or simply check `if (getActivity() != null)`

Answer (score 1):

`getActivity()` returns null only when your `Fragment` is not attached. In my experience your error usually happens when you are doing some asynchronous process before calling the method and user has navigated away from your `Fragment`.

Typically you want to do nothing if user has left the `Fragment` so a simple `if (getActivity() != null)` should to it for you.

Other cases that may cause this error is when you are calling this method from outside your `Fragment` class. For example you have just instantiated the `Fragment` and call your method before even attaching it to your `Activity`. In which case you should know calling `Fragment` methods from outside the `Fragment` class is a very bad experience. And you have to change your logic so the `Fragment` itself will decide "when" to call its methods.

Comment: good points! I'll remember that. would declaring getactivity static solve it?

Comment: It won't be a good practice even if it works. Because you would want your Fragment to be completely reusable. Imagine a scenario in which you put two instances of your Fragment into the View hierarchy. Also to my knowledge OS might nullify your non final static variables. So there is a huge risk there.

You should focus on why user has navigated away from your Fragment. If you still need to do some action, you should do so through setting a result in say a Singleton object with a specific purpose. Other elements of your app can "listen" to changes of that result.