# getActivity().getPackageManager() showing null?

Tags: java, android-studio

I have tried removing the if condition but didn't work, also it's inside the fragment so no context issue.

```
button = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
url = view.findViewById(R.id.Url);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String s= url.getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(s));

        if (intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else{
            url.setText("Error");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Null pointer crash on getActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46752480/null-pointer-crash-on-getactivity-getpackagemanager-queryintentactivities)

Answer (score 1):

It's not `getActivity().getPackageManager()`that is `null`.
It's `intent.resolveActivity` that returns `null`
And this simply means that there doesn't exist an activity that can handle the `Uri` that you provided. Be sure to write your uri correct